# ros Header: increasing "seq" in service calls?

Tags: ros, service, message, header

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a srv that contains a msg, which contains a ROS Header. I have two static variables inside main: one with a message and one with a service (containing request/response and wrapped inside the request the message of the previous type).

When I publish several messages, the seq-field of the Header is increased.

When I execute a service call, the sequence number is not increased.

Bug, misunderstanding or bad luck?

using ROS Electric...

Greetings
Marvin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38856/ros-header:-increasing-%22seq%22-in-service-calls?/) by [mavin2k](https://answers.ros.org/users/2848/mavin2k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mavin2k](https://answers.ros.org/users/2848/mavin2k/) on 2012-07-16**:
I'm surprised by this behaviour, because of the difference between "topic" and "service call" where both have the same magic "Header". What is this "Header" supposed to do? It should increment the "seq" field every time something goes over the wire -- or not, I don't care. But not sometimes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with @dornhege that this behavior is probably not correct.

But, I suspect the `seq` field may not be supported in some future transport implementation. So, I would not recommend depending on it.

Perhaps you can accomplish what you need via the `header.stamp` field.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-09-06**:
The seq field has been deprecated.  It cannot be depended upon to increment depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my perspective this would be the correct behavior.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1